# Object Does Not Support Indexing

Tags: python, indexing

I'm creating a work log in python where a user can enter a task or can lookup a task by date.  My initial prompt asks user to either enter a task or lookup by date.  If the user starts by looking up by date--the program works correctly and displays all dates.  If a user starts by adding a task, and then looking up tasks by date, the program displays an 'object does not support indexing error'. I think for some reason, the list is getting emptied, but i can't for the life of me understand where or when this might be happening.  Here is main worklog file:

```
import csv
import re
import datetime
from task import Task
from task_list import TaskList


class Worklog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = "work_log.csv"
        self.tasklist = TaskList()
        self.tasklist.read_task_from_file(self.filename)

    def search_by_date(self):
        for d, i in enumerate(self.tasklist.dates()):
            print(d+1, ':', i)
        # while True:
        #     datereq = input("Select Number To See Tasks For A Date").strip().lower()
        #     try:
        #         datereq = int(datereq)
        #         return datereq
        #     except ValueError:
        #         print("Invalid Entry. Please try again")
        #         continue

    def search_by_time(self):
        pass

    def exact_search(self):
        pass

    def pattern_search(self):
        pass

    def add_task(self):
        task = Task()
        task.input_task()
        task.input_minutes()
        task.input_notes()
        task.date = datetime.date.today()
        self.tasklist.app_task(task)
        self.tasklist.save_task_to_file(self.filename,task)

    def lookup_task(self):
        if len(self.tasklist.task_list) == 0:
            print("Your task log is empty.\n")
            input("Hit Enter to add a new task.")
        else:
            while True:
                lookup = input("Lookup by Date(D), Time(T), Exact Search(E) or Pattern(P): ")
                lookup.lower()

                if lookup == 'd':
                    self.search_by_date()
                    break
                elif lookup == 't':
                    self.search_by_time()
                    break
                elif lookup == 'e':
                    self.exact_search()
                    break
                elif lookup == 'p':
                    self.pattern_search()
                    break
                else:
                    print("Sorry invalid option. Please try again")

    def start_message(self):
        while True:

            q = input("Add New Task(1) or Lookup Task(2) or Quit(3): ".strip().lower())

            if q == "1":
                self.add_task()

            elif q == "2":
                self.lookup_task()

            elif q == "3":
                exit()

            else:
                print("Sorry that's an invalid entry. Please try again.")
                continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = Worklog()
    log.start_message()
```

The error is pointing to the *dates* function which is shown below along with a few of the other methods for my 'task-list' class. Is there an issue with the way that I am indexing this list?  Or am i right in that the task_list list is getting reset somehow when the user enters the second step of the loop.  Thanks:

```
    def app_task(self, task):
        self.task_list.append(task)

    def save_task_to_file(self,filename,task):
        with open(filename, 'a', newline="\n", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
            # creating a csv writer object
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
            # writing the data rows
            csvwriter.writerow([task.date, task.task, task.minutes, task.notes])

    def read_task_from_file(self,filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            task_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in task_reader:
                task = Task()
                self.task_list.append(row)
        return self.task_list

    def dates(self):
        self.read_task_from_file("work_log.csv")
        dates = []
        for row in self.task_list:
            date = row[0]
            if row[0] not in dates:
                dates.append(date)
        return sorted(dates)
```

Note--here is an example of what the work_log.csv file looks like:

```
2017-03-23,gardening,30,not really
2017-03-23,bowling,30,none
2017-03-23,bowling,90,none
2017-03-23,bowling,93,none
2017-03-23,baseball,2,none
2017-03-23,bowling,20,none
2017-03-23,base,0,jj
2017-03-23,bowling,33,none
```

Added per Jake's recommendation:

```
def get_date(self):
        for row in self.task_list:
            d = row[0]
            return d

    def dates(self):
        dates = []
        for row in dates:
            date = row.get_date()
            if date not in dates:
                dates.append(date)
        return sorted(dates)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? What line is this on and what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: "C:/Users/c/PycharmProjects/worklog/work_log.py", line 88, in <module>
    log.start_message()
  File "C:/Users/c/PycharmProjects/worklog/work_log.py", line 77, in start_message
    self.lookup_task()
  File "C:/Users/c/PycharmProjects/worklog/work_log.py", line 54, in lookup_task
    self.search_by_date()
  File "C:/Users/c/PycharmProjects/worklog/work_log.py", line 15, in search_by_date
    for d, i in enumerate(self.tasklist.dates()):
  File "C:\Users\c\PycharmProjects\worklog\task_list.py", line 34, in dates
    date = row[0]
TypeError: 'Task' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be where you call `date = row[0]`; this is because in the loop `row` will be a `Task` object as you are iterating over `self.task_list`. In this case you are trying to index into a `Task` object, which is not set up for indexing.

The simple solution for this would be to replace `row[0]` with `row.date`; which will directly access the `date` field of the `row` object, without needing to bother about indexing at all.

Comment: Thanks @jake.  Per 1 -- is this sort of what you're getting at?   


 `def get_date(self):
        for row in self.task_list:
            d = row[0]
            return d`

    `def dates(self):
        dates = []
        for row in dates:
            date = row.get_date()
            if date not in dates:
                dates.append(date)
        return sorted(dates)`

Comment: for some reason not returning anything now

Comment: note i added code to end of original post to make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't quite right @John Rogerson, because now you are trying to iterate over a `Nothing` value. To simplify this could you include the code for your `Task` class? Once I see this I can modify my answer to fully clarify what I mean and to help with your code. If the class is particularly large, then consider copying it to PasteBin, or some other similar site.

Comment: right--seeing that now.  okay here is my git repository:  https://github.com/pythoncreate/worklog/tree/master

Comment: tried changing to row.date and getting a new error AttributeError pointing to the date = row.date line---: 'list' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: I'm not certain how you're getting this error in particular. You have somehow got `row` to be a `list`, which means you may have appended a `list` rather than a `Task` to the `TaskList`

Comment: In fact on a second reading of `TaskList.read_task_from_file` you iterate over the rows in the csv file, then create a `Task` object, but then append the row and not the task to the list.

Comment: You would because at that point you're adding a `list` object to `task_list`. I was under the impression that `task_list` was to be a `list` containing `Task` objects. I think your problem is that currently `task_list` could contain `Task`s, `list`s or a combination of the two. You should probably work to ensure it only ever contains the one type of object that you want.

Comment: think i see what you're getting at though changed it to             `for row in task_reader:
                task = Task()
                task.date = row[0]
                task.task = row[1]
                task.minutes = row[2]
                task.notes = row[3]
                self.task_list.append(task)`