# RDD and tuple manipulation with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have just started using Spark and I have a problem that I don't really know how to approach.

My input is an RDD of the form:

```
[(u'7362', (u'2016-06-29 09:58:35', 0)), (u'8600', (u'2016-06-29 20:47:27', 1)), (u'f9f8', (u'2016-07-01 00:48:55', 2)), (u'c6c9', (u'2016-07-04 20:29:19', 3)), (u'218b', (u'2016-07-05 20:54:45', 4))]
```

so the structure is

```
[(user_id, (time_stamp, index))]
```

What I need to do is return a list of lists, or list of tuples.

This is easier if we look at the RDD in table format. Say this is the above rdd in a more "classical" table form.

```
[(u'7362', (u'2016-06-29 09:58:35', 0)), 
(u'8600', (u'2016-06-29 20:47:27', 1)), 
(u'7362', (u'2016-07-01 00:48:55', 2)), 
(u'c6c9', (u'2016-07-04 20:29:19', 3)), 
(u'8600', (u'2016-07-05 20:54:45', 4))]
```

I need to first group this RDD by user, so I will end-up with three RDDs (one for each user, and one for the non-repeating users).

```
[(u'7362', (u'2016-06-29 09:58:35', 0)), 
(u'7362', (u'2016-07-01 00:48:55', 2))]

[(u'8600', (u'2016-06-29 20:47:27', 1)), 
(u'8600', (u'2016-07-05 20:54:45', 4))]

[(u'c6c9', (u'2016-07-04 20:29:19', 3))]
```

Now, for the "tables" containing just one user_id (first two) I need to take the time differences of every line with the previous line, and for every index with every previous index (consider that these "tables" have much more than 2 rows). 
This would give tables like:

```
[(u'7362', (35, 2)), (u'7362', (21, 1)), (u'7362', (12, 3)), (u'7362', (41, 2)), (u'7362', (46, 2)), (u'7362', (31, 1)), (u'7362', (97, 3)) ...]
```

for the first user_id,

```
[(u'8600', (78, 2)), (u'8600', (43, 1)), (u'8600', (99, 3)), (u'8600', (3, 2)), (u'8600', (15, 2)), (u'8600', (42, 1)), (u'8600', (11, 3)) ...]
```

and so on, for all users, where the format is `[(user_idx, (dt=t2-t1, didx=idx2-idx1))]` and `dt` and `didx` are taken by subtracting the previous row values from the current row values, for all rows.

Finally, when I have all the above tables, for every user, I want to group them in a single nested list as:

```
[[1, [21, 31, 43, 42]], [2, [35, 41, 46, 78, 3, 15]], [3, [12, 97, 99, 11]]]
```

so the final format is `[[didx, [dt1, dt2 ...]]` where I don't care about the user_ids anymore, just the indices and every time difference related to the same index, from all users.

I tried to explain the problem as clearly as I can, but, like I said, I have really just gotten started with Spark and I understand there are no real tables here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you groupBy the userId, this does not result in multiple RDDs, but one RDD in the form of RDD[(UserId, list[(time, index)]. So in this case, I would do the groupBy, then process the user lists into the format, then groupBy the didx as you said, then finally collect the result from an RDD to list.

```
# assume each user has more than one event 
# if this ^ assumption is incorrect, you could filter the RDD before processing to get rid of users 
# with only one event
# also, assume timesteps can be subtracted (there are libraries for this)
def process(indexedTimes):
    num_times = len(indexedTimes)
    new_list = []
    for i in range(1,num_times):
        new_list.append((indexedTimes[i][1]-indexedTimes[i-1][1],datediff(indexedTimes[i][0]-indexedTimes[i-1][0])))
    return new_list

data                                                     # RDD[(userId, (timestep, index))]
  .groupByKey                                            # now RDD[(userId, list[(timestep, index)])]
  .flatMap(lambda userList: process(list(userList[1])))  # now RDD[(didx, dt)]
  .groupByKey                                            # now RDD[(didx, list(dt))]
  .collect                                               # get elements in final list instead of RDD
```

Comment: Hi and thank you so much for your answer. One small thing, a " ) " needs to be inserted after .flatMap. I implemented this and it runs a bit, but then it throws a : 

    TypeError: 'ResultIterable' object does not support indexing. 

However I found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978738/object-does-not-support-indexing

But I don't know how to adapt it to the indexedTimes elements.

Comment: ah yeah I see what you mean, you can typecast the ResultIterable object to a list prior to the function and it should work. I edited the answer

Comment: So that almost solved it. I am now getting an error because my times cannot be subtracted. I replaced your line in the function with

`datediff(indexedTimes[i][1], indexedTimes[i-1][1])`

but I get a :

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'.`

and I am sure it is due to that `diff` function.

Comment: the date is in `indexedTimes[i][0]`, not `indexedTimes[i][1]`. In other words, you're trying to use the datediff on the index, not the date. In the function, the (date, index) is reversed to (difference of index, difference of date) because you want to groupBy the difference of index, so this value needs to be first in the tuple. so try moving the datediff to the `indexedTimes[i][0]-indexedTimes[i-1][0]` as opposed to `indexedTimes[i][1]-indexedTimes[i-1][1]`. I edited the answer

Comment: if you still get the same error, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297403/pyspark-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-jvm

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I will test this answer first thing Monday morning, and let you know if it works. Thanks again for writing the answer.